# Unable to execute "remote-exec" provisioner in Azure terraform

Tags: azure, terraform

I am trying to execute remote-exec provisioner when deploying a VM in Azure but inline code in remote-exec never executes.

Here is my provisioner and connection code:

```
provisioner "remote-exec" {

    inline = [
    "touch newfile.txt",
    "touch newfile2.txt",
    ]
}

connection {
        type = "ssh"
        host = "${azurerm_public_ip.publicip.ip_address}"
        user  = "testuser"
        private_key = "${file("~/.ssh/id_rsa")}"
        agent = false
}
```

Code never executes and gives the error:
Error: Failed to read ssh private key: no key found

The key (id_rsa) is saved in the same location of the VM where I am running the main.tf file.

Please suggest what is wrong here.

Comment: Your code is telling Terraform that the key is in your home directory under `.ssh/id_rsa` (the ~/ expands to your home directory). If the key isn't there then you should either move the key to there or update the path in your Terraform code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ydaetskcoR comment, your code `private_key = "${file("~/.ssh/id_rsa")}"` indicated that the private key should exist at `.ssh/id_rsa` under your home directoty like `/home/username` on linux or `C:\Users\username` on windows.

You could save that key (id_rsa) in that directory as your code, otherwise, you need to add the current path of the key in your code.

For example, edit it to `private_key = "${file("${path.module}/id_rsa")}"`